# The 'ModifiedOn' property on 'WareHouse' could not be set to a 'DateTime' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is my controller class.

```
namespace CalcoWOMS.Controllers
{ 
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private WOMSEntities db = new WOMSEntities();

        public ViewResult WareHouseIndex()
        {
            return View(db.WareHouse.ToList());
        }



        public ViewResult WareHouseDetails(int id)
        {
            WareHouse wareHouse = db.WareHouse.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            return View(wareHouse);
        }

        public ActionResult WareHouseCreate()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(WareHouse wareHouse)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.WareHouse.AddObject(wareHouse);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("WareHouseIndex");
            }

            return View(wareHouse);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Admin/Edit/5

        public ActionResult WareHouseEdit(int id)
        {
            WareHouse wareHouse = db.WareHouse.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            return View(wareHouse);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WareHouseEdit(WareHouse wareHouse)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.WareHouse.Attach(wareHouse);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(wareHouse, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("WareHouseIndex");
            }
            return View(wareHouse);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Admin/Delete/5

        public ActionResult WareHouseDelete(int id)
        {
            WareHouse wareHouse = db.WareHouse.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            return View(wareHouse);
        }


        [HttpPost, ActionName("WareHouseDelete")]
        public ActionResult WareHouseDeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            WareHouse wareHouse = db.WareHouse.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            db.WareHouse.DeleteObject(wareHouse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("WareHouseIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my table design..

[image: this is image of my table design]

whenever i want to run "Admin/WareHouseIndex"  action there is a problem occured is
"The 'ModifiedOn' property on 'WareHouse' could not be set to a 'DateTime' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'."

even i there is no null entry in modifiedOn field. Please check it and suggest me what mistake i have done.

Comment: What type of exception is this? What is the type of your WareHouse.ModifiedOn property and how is it attributed? How is it mapped to the database?

Comment: Can you show the code, specifically the constructor, for the class WareHouse? And I assume you are using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a mismatch of types between your `Database Type` and your `POCO Type` for that property. If I had to guess I'd say your property type is a `String` or a non-nullable DateTime and it should be a nullable `DateTime`, ie:

```
public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
```